# how to stop at a specific point in a list

Tags: bash, shell-script, less

I created a shell script called `blossom()` because my girlfriend's dog Blossom poops and pees on the floor all the time.

```
blossom() {
   echo poops and pees on floor all the time
}
```

Because I am such a curious kid, I want to search where this shell is stored and found on some forum that it is within `declare -f`. So I want to find it in the output but also read around it again.

I had some ideas and tried

```
declare -f | grep blossom
```

well, that only showed the top line which was `blossom() {`

So I thought, hm... let's try

```
declare -f | less
```

but that is still too much to search through...

what about

```
declare -f > test_file
nano test_file
```

well this one does solve some of what I am trying to do and I can use <kbd>^W</kbd> for "Where at" and find it no problem. But this creates a file and I do not want to do that.

How can I, with a certain set of commands, pre-search an output with scroll up and down capability. Maybe using `less` command and have that pre-searched. Is this possible?

Comment: Why not `declare -f blossom`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following to start `less` with `blossom` already searched for:

```
declare -f | less -p blossom
```

From the documentation of `less`:

```
-ppattern or --pattern=pattern
    The -p option on the command line is  equivalent  to  specifying
    +/pattern;  that  is, it tells less to start at the first occur‐
    rence of pattern in the file.
```

If your question was less general than that, and you want just the source for function `blossom`, use the following:

```
declare -f blossom
```

Comment: Sometimes Ill read documentation and scan over that very thing, and just not know what it means. Thank you! I kinda feel silly, since I scanned the docs already and missed this!

It seems that both of your answers were incredibly helpful! Thanks!